# Aggregate count in Pandas

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

I want to apply a group by on a pandas dataframe. I want to group by three columns and calculate their count. I used the following code

```
data.groupby(['post_product_list','cust_visid','date_time']).count()
```

But it didn't seem to work

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data.groupby(['post_product_list','cust_visid','date_time']).size()
```

Comment: Thanks. I did try this. But I got another problem. The dataframe loses the names of the columns and I cannot rename them. Any solution to that?